# how to solve key error with this python code?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

```
# creating the prediction results for the image classification and shifting the predicted images to another folder
# with renamed filename having the class name predicted for that image using model

with open(os.path.join(JSON_DIR, 'class_name_map.json')) as secret_input:
    info = json.load(secret_input)

for i in range(data_test.shape[0]):
    new_name = data_test.iloc[i, 0].split("/")[-1].split(".")[0] + "_" + info[data_test.iloc[i, 1]] + ".jpg"
    shutil.copy(data_test.iloc[i, 0], os.path.join(PREDICT_DIR, new_name))

# saving the model predicted results into a csv file
data_test.to_csv(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "csv_files", "short_test_result.csv"), index=False)
```

---

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
7
8 for i in range(data_test.shape[0]):
----> 9     new_name = data_test.iloc[i,0].split("/")[-1].split(".")[0]+"_"+info[data_test.iloc[i,1]]+".jpg"
10     shutil.copy(data_test.iloc[i,0],os.path.join(PREDICT_DIR,new_name))
11

KeyError: 'c2 '